How to add a custom UITabBarController with scrollEdgeAppearance
I created my custom UITabBarController as below programatically.
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        viewControllers = [
            //<- adding my UIViewControllers embedded in UINavigationControllers here
        ]
    
        configureTabbar()
    }

    func configureTabbar() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = AppColors.mainBgColor
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = AppColors.tabbarTintColor
    
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15
    
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 45, y: self.tabBar.bounds.minY - 10, width: self.tabBar.bounds.width - 90, height: self.tabBar.bounds.height + 10), cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 25.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.opacity = 1.0
        layer.isHidden = false
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.fillColor = AppColors.tabbarBG.cgColor
    
        self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
    
        if let items = self.tabBar.items {
            items.forEach { item in
                item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -15, right: 0)
            }
        }
    
        self.tabBar.itemWidth = 30.0
        self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered
    }

    -------------
    -------------
    -------------

}

Below is the output

Issue I have with ScrollView
I have a UICollectionView in one of my UIViewControllers and the Scroll gives below.

How to make the UI unchanged for scrollEdgeAppearance by keeping the same Look and Feel of the Custom Tabbar View I created and disable the transparency of the Tabbar in this case??

I found a tweak for the above issue as below.
func configureTabbar() {
    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBar.appearance()
    tabBarAppearance.isTranslucent = false
    tabBarAppearance.barTintColor = AppColors.tabbarTintColor
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = AppColors.mainBgColor

    //UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = AppColors.mainBgColor
    //UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = AppColors.tabbarTintColor

.......
.......

}

With the above change, the transparency of the Tabbar issue with UICollectionView was fixed without making the UI cluttered. However the barTintColor becomes default blue. Then I  uncommented the below line and now the Appearance is fixed.
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = AppColors.tabbarTintColor

If anyone come across any sort of a solution different than to this, I would like if you can post a reply here. Hope this helps someone in the future.
